# discord.py で ループじゃなくて対話モードでログインしたい

Tags: python, discord

```py
import discord

client = discord.Client()

client.run(TOKEN)
```

これだとループになってしまい対話モードにできないです。
対話モードでログインするにはどうすればいいですか。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　質問文下の「編集」から、Pythonのバージョンとdiscord.pyのバージョンを追記してくださいませんか？

Answer (score 0):

対話モードというのが具体的にはどういう動作を指しているのか分からなかったのですが、[discord.py の README](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/a136def52f72a0b100711b4b47950f57179bfa2d/README.rst#quick-example) に書いてあるこのサンプルコードが参考になるかもしれません。送られてきたメッセージが "ping" であれば "pong" と返すサンプルです。

```
import discord

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as', self.user)

    async def on_message(self, message):
        # don't respond to ourselves
        if message.author == self.user:
            return

        if message.content == 'ping':
            await message.channel.send('pong')

client = MyClient()
client.run('token')
```